# how to perform arithmetic operations with different containers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two panels in my form.  I created two functions to get all the textboxes and their values. I need a way to get multiplication values i.e (using the first textbox in `panel1` to multiply the first textbox in `panel2` and so on).

```
Private Function getallTextBoxes(ByVal container As ContainerControl) As Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)

    Dim allTextBoxes As New Dictionary(Of String, TextBox)

    For Each ctrl As Control In container.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            allTextBoxes.Add(ctrl.Name, ctrl)
        End If
    Next
    Return allTextBoxes
End Function


Private Function getTextBoxValues(ByVal textBoxDefs As IDictionary(Of String, TextBox)) As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Dim textBoxValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each tbxDef As KeyValuePair(Of String, TextBox) In textBoxDefs
        Dim tbx As TextBox = tbxDef.Value
        Dim name As String = tbx.Name
        Dim value As String = tbx.Text
        textBoxValues.Add(name, value)
    Next
    Return textBoxValues
End Function
```

Comment: Not C#. Don't tag spam.

Comment: The order of things in a Dictionary is undefined, so there is no concept of 'first', 'third' etc